# SFML - Weird RenderTexture behaviour when resizing window

Tags: c++, sfml

I am currently trying to recreate Chess in SFML. Generating the board normally works as intended but when I am resizing the window I get weird white borders.

Before Resize:

[image]

After Resize:

[image]

It looks like the view is not aligned with the window properly so I think my problem is not in the board generation but how I am handling resizes. I thought manually updating the window view would help but it only ensured that the squares don't get streched. The border issue remains however so now I am quite clueless as to how I could fix this problem.

Board.h:

```
#pragma once

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

class Board
{
public:
    void createBoard(sf::Vector2u windowSize);
    void drawBoard(sf::RenderWindow& window) const;

private:
    sf::RenderTexture board;
    sf::Color lightColor = sf::Color(159, 144, 176);
    sf::Color darkColor = sf::Color(125, 74, 141);
    sf::Color backColor = sf::Color(32, 31, 32);
};
```

Board.cpp:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

#include "Board.h"

void Board::createBoard(sf::Vector2u windowSize)
{
    const float xOffset = static_cast<float>(windowSize.x - windowSize.y) / 2.f;
    const float squareSize = static_cast<float>(windowSize.y) / 8.f;

    board.create(windowSize.x, windowSize.y);
    board.clear(backColor);

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            sf::RectangleShape currSquare({ squareSize, squareSize });
            currSquare.setFillColor((i + j) % 2 ? lightColor : darkColor);
            currSquare.setPosition(xOffset + static_cast<float>(i) * squareSize, (static_cast<float>(j) * squareSize));
            board.draw(currSquare);
        }
    }
}

void Board::drawBoard(sf::RenderWindow& window) const
{
    window.draw(sf::Sprite(board.getTexture()));
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

#include "Board.h"

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(500, 300), "Chess");
    sf::Event event;
    sf::View view = window.getDefaultView();

    Board board;
    board.createBoard(window.getSize());

    while (window.isOpen()) {
        while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed) {
                window.close();
            }
            else if (event.type == sf::Event::Resized) {
                view.setSize({ static_cast<float>(event.size.width), static_cast<float>(event.size.height) });
                window.setView(view);
                board.createBoard({ event.size.width, event.size.height });
            }
        }

        window.clear(sf::Color::White);
        board.drawBoard(window);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Does anyone know how I could fix this problem?

Comment: Show definition of `board.getTexture()`.

Comment: @rafix07 `board` is a RenderTexture so `board.getTexture()` is a function defined internally by SFML. But yes, I should probably clarify that board is a RenderTexture

Comment: Calling `sf::RenderTexture::display` in `drawBoard` before `window.draw` may help.

Comment: @rafix07 I tried calling `board.display()` already and it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you don't only need to resize the view, but also **recenter it**. As right now you are not doing it, the center remains where the smaller board was and the bigger view takes a chunk from the outside in the top left corner.

So just change your code like this:

```
...
else if (event.type == sf::Event::Resized) {
    float w = static_cast<float>(event.size.width);
    float h = static_cast<float>(event.size.height);
    view.setSize({w , h});
    view.setCenter({w/2.f , h/2.f}); // <----- !
    window.setView(view);
    board.createBoard({ event.size.width, event.size.height });
}
...
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That makes a lot of sense now (: